# nomore UDID - how to store settings for push notification per device?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, udid

Udid deprecated - how would you store the settings for push notification per device now?

How does everyone else store push settings per device?

Can we use the iphone/ipad MAC Address? or will apple ban the app?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Apple's rejection policies. See also: [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
@interface UIDevice (UIDeviceAppIdentifier)
@property (readonly) NSString *deviceApplicationIdentifier;
@end

@implementation UIDevice (UIDeviceAppIdentifier)
- (NSString *) deviceApplicationIdentifier
{ 
  static NSString *name     = @"a string identifying your application, like its name";
  NSUserDefaults  *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];  
  NSString        *value    = [defaults objectForKey: name];

  if (!value)
    {
      value = (NSString *) CFUUIDCreateString (NULL, CFUUIDCreate(NULL));    
      [defaults setObject: value forKey: name];
      [defaults synchronize]; // handle error
  }
  return value;
}
@end
```

the iOS documentation more or less describes use of CFUUIDCreate() to create an identifier and suggests using UserDefaults to store it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this project

http://www.secureudid.org/